# Combine First Row with All Other Rows | Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm attempting to find all the possible purchase routes for customers. The way I currently have the data presented looks like the following:

```
email           purchase_order  sku      first_order  second_order  third_order  
abc@email.com   1               PS2525   PS2525       null          null         
abc@email.com   2               PS2525   PS2525       PS2525        null         
abc@email.com   2               LG1515   PS2525       LG1515        null         
abc@email.com   3               PS2525   PS2525       null          PS2525       
abc@email.com   3               RG7578   PS2525       null          RG7578
```

But what I'm looking for is the route of each purchase. I'd like my data to look like this:

```
email           first_order  second_order  third_order  
abc@email.com   PS2525       PS2525        PS2525       
abc@email.com   PS2525       PS2525        RG7578       
abc@email.com   PS2525       LG1515        PS2525       
abc@email.com   PS2525       LG1515        RG7578
```

This shows every route that the customer took after their first order. Is there a way I can create this type of table? I'm having a hard time thinking of a way to make this happen.

Comment: just three orders as a max number of orders?

Comment: yes, just three orders as the limit i'm setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT email, o1.sku AS first_order, o2.sku AS second_order, o3.sku AS third_order
FROM `project.dataset.table` o1
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` o2
USING(email) 
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` o3
USING(email) 
WHERE o1.purchase_order = 1
AND o2.purchase_order = 2
AND o3.purchase_order = 3
```

If applied to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row email           first_order second_order    third_order  
1   abc@email.com   PS2525      PS2525          PS2525   
2   abc@email.com   PS2525      PS2525          RG7578   
3   abc@email.com   PS2525      LG1515          PS2525   
4   abc@email.com   PS2525      LG1515          RG7578
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want aggregation:

```
select email, sku, max(first_order), max(second_order), max(third_order)
from t
group by email, sku;
```